# ¿Como puedo declarar correctamente el segundo If?

Tags: java

En mi código tengo que indicar que tipo de triangulo es en base a los valores entregados en las variables "a", "b", "c" 
* Si `c>= a+b`. No se trata de un triángulo.
 * Si `c^2 = a^2 + b^2`. Es un triángulo rectángulo.
 * Si `c^2 > a^2 + b^2`. Se forma un triángulo obtusángulo.
 * Si `c^2 < a^2 + b^2`. Se forma un triángulo acutangulo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
        double a, b, c, resul;

        //Pedimos los valores de el triangulo a,b,c.

    System.out.println("Tipos de Triángulos ");
    System.out.print("a: ");
    a=leer.nextInt();
    System.out.print("b: ");
    b=leer.nextInt();
    System.out.print("c: ");
    c=leer.nextInt();

    if(c>=(a+b)){
        System.out.println("No se trata de un triángulo ");
    }
    else{
        if(Math.pow(c, 2)= (Math.pow(a, 2)+ Math.pow(b, 2))){ //En esta parte es mi pregunta, tengo que indicar que: C esta al cuadrado, al igual que A y B. para poder evaluar el caso y determinar que tipo de triangulo es.

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos agrupar métodos:

```
int x = (int) Math.pow(c, 2);
int y = (int) Math.pow(a, 2);
int z = (int) Math.pow(b, 2);
int w = y + z;

r = x.compareTo(w);

switch (r) {
    case 0:
       System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo rectangulo");
       break;
    case 1:
       System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo obtusángulo");
       break;
    case -1:
       System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo acutangulo");
       break;
}
```

En caso sea Double:

```
int r = Double.compare(x, w);

if(r > 0) {
    System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo obtusángulo");
} else if(r < 0) {
    System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo acutangulo");
} else {
    System.out.println("Se trata de un triángulo rectangulo");
}
```

Slds

Comment: Lo resolví usando los (int) z,y,z, el Math.pow y en lugar de usar switch preferi usar if anidados, logre resolver el problema rapidamente, gracias.